# Controlling Branching of PHP with either HTML Buttons or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

I'm in the process of developing a web app that interfaces to a MySQL file with PHP.  Before I add a record, with eight fields, I'd like to ask the user to confirm the data.  The only way that I can think of doing this is with a  that would contain a prompt, a 'yes' button, and a 'no' button.

If 'yes' is chosen, the record is added to the database.  If 'no' the user is bounced back to the input form, another .php file.

But, I need a way to get the HTML buttons to take different branches of my .php structure.  I know, the buttons are front-end, while the .php code is server side.  Still, there must be a way to get PHP to alter behavior with either HTML and/or JavaScript.  The only thing that comes to mind, is to send the results of the button presses to different Forms?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `confirm()` in Javascript to confirm

You could easily use `confirm()` to prompt the user. This will be implemented by the browser so you don't need to worry about design. Simply force the form to prompt the user (Add the submit listener), then it will return a true/false value based on their click. You can then proceed (do nothing to prevent submit) or block the submission.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (!confirmed) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

Comment: I will try that bit of code, thank you!  But, it dawned on me yesterday, thinking about how PHP handles branching, that using nav type buttons is probably the most cut and dry solution.  Have a link to the .php file that performs the affirmative, (an include file) and one that goes back to the main input form for the negative response.  I can see a real need for a framework, that bridges client-side and server-side processes.  From what I gather, that's what Node JS does.

Comment: @CodeSchlocker Node is a server side JS Runtime, It would actually replace PHP. The technology you're looking for is actually called [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX). Or if you're doing heavy communication, [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) can do real time between server and client.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll get around to learning that technology eventually.  For right now, I have two nav buttons (links) that perform excellently.  I was having some real issues with adding a record with a foreign key, but, there was a couple of real good answers on this site, that got me over that roadblock.  I've just started web development, and, it's amazing all the roadblocks you hit.  Google, and stackoverflow have been my best friends.